# NodeJS - The Node Beginner Book - show function not getting called

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am following the guide in the **Node Beginner Book** and have managed to get all the way through to the last section, **Handling file uploads**.  This book focuses on JavaScript calling methods and using request and response with very little HTML included only as strings when necessary.

All my console.log statements are showing me the correct file path.  But instead of displaying the image I get the following HTML line:

[image]

I think the problem is in this line in **requestHandlers.js**:

```
response.write("<img src='/show' />");
```

It is supposed to be calling the **show function** at the bottom of **requestHandlers.js**.  Look at the **Console output** at the bottom of this post and you can see that **execution never gets into the show function**.  Source code and Console output is below:

**index.js**

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");

var handle = {};
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;
handle["/show"] = requestHandlers.show;

server.start(router.route, handle);
```

**server.js**

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(route, handle) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
    route(handle, pathname, response, request);
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
  console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

**router.js**

```
function route(handle, pathname, response, request) {
  console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
  if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
    handle[pathname](response, request);
  } else {
    console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
    response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("404 Not found");
    response.end();
  }
}

exports.route = route;
```

**requestHandlers.js**

```
var querystring = require("querystring"), 
        fs = require("fs"),
        formidable = require("formidable");
var path = require('path');
var file = path.join(__dirname, 'tmp', "test.png");

function start(response) {
  console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");

  var body = '<html>'+
      '<head>'+
            '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'+
      '</head>'+
          '<body>'+
                '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
                  '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"/>'+
                  '<input type="submit" value="Upload file"/>'+
                '</form>'+
          '</body>'+
    '</html>';

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.write(body);
    response.end();
}

function upload(response, request) {
  console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  console.log("about to parse");
  form.parse(request, function(error, fields, files) {
    console.log("parsing done");
    console.log("File = "+file);

    fs.rename(files.upload.path, file,  function (error) {
        if(error) {
            console.log("error");
            fs.unlink(file);
            console.log(file);
            fs.rename(files.upload.path, file);
            console.log(file);
        }
    });
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("received image:<br/>");
    response.write("<img src='/show' />");
    response.end();
  });
}

function show(response) {
    console.log("Request handler 'show' was called.");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "image/png"});
    fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(response);
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
exports.show = show;
```

> **Console output**

```
C:\Users\pdl\Projects\TestSeparateJS>node index.js
Server has started.
Request for / received.
About to route a request for /
Request handler 'start' was called.
Request for /upload received.
About to route a request for /upload
Request handler 'upload' was called.
about to parse
parsing done
File = C:\Users\pdl\Projects\TestSeparateJS\tmp\test.png
error
C:\Users\pdl\Projects\TestSeparateJS\tmp\test.png
C:\Users\pdl\Projects\TestSeparateJS\tmp\test.png
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending the content as plaintext instead of HTML. So the browser never runs it as HTML. That's why you see the `<img>` text instead of an `<img>` tag being generated.

In your `upload` function change this:

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
```

to this:

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a newer version of node.js, you also might like to change the code files.upload.**path** into files.upload.**filepath**